# css settings not working in codeigniter

Tags: php

I can not get the CSS settings in CodeIgniter, living below the changes I made. can someone help me there where wrong?

file autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html','text');
```

file in the home folder controllers

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('html_header');
        $this->load->view('cabecalho');
        $this->load->view('corpo');
        $this->load->view('rodape');
        $this->load->view('html_footer');
    }

}
```

I created the following css folder in path / css / teste.css

php files created in folder views

cabecalho.php corpo.php rodape.php html_header.php html_footer.php

html_header.php folder and put this line of code

```
<?php echo doctype('xhtml1-trans'); ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Meu website de receitas</title>
        <?php
        $meta = array(
            array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'no-cache'),
            array('name' => 'description', 'content' => 'Meu website de receitas'),
            array('name' => 'keywords', 'content' => 'Receitas, doces, salgados, sobremesas, massas'),
            array('name' => 'robots', 'content' => 'no-cache'),
            array('name' => 'Content-type', 'content' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'type' => 'equiv')
        );
        echo meta($meta);

        echo link_tag('caminho/css/teste.css');
        ?>
    </head>
<body>
```

teste.css the folder has the following configuration

```
#cabecalho{background-color: #ddd; float: left; width: 824px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px;}
```

being that it does not work.

Comment: what error you getting

Comment: worked not putting link_tag ('css / teste.css');

Comment: try echo link_tag('css/teste.css');

Answer (score 2):

when you have css like first:

**`<?php echo base_url(); ?>/css/style.css`**

css folder should be in root directory before application .

Answer (score 0):

you need to add your css like (if css dir on root of CI )

```
echo link_tag('css/teste.css');
```

else (if css dir in under other dir)

```
   echo link_tag('other/css/teste.css');
```

for more info follow :- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html
and also try to ctrl+u or view source is css path is ok